# Array modifications

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays

```
arrNew = [
    { RecordId: '181049' },
    { RecordId: '187020'},
    { RecordId: '187022'}
]

arrOld = [
    { RecordId: '181049', DateCreated: 1563447093134 },
    { RecordId: '187020', DateCreated: 1563447093134 },
    { RecordId: '187021', DateCreated: 1563447093134 }
]
```

What I need to do is to get `RecordId` from `arrNew` and check if that record is present in `arrOld`. If yes then copy `DateCreated` associated with that `RecordId` to `arrNew`, but if record is new (only exist in `newArr`) add a `DateCreate` equals to today's date.

Expected result:

```
arrNew = [
    { RecordId: '181049', DateCreated: 1563447093134 },
    { RecordId: '187020', DateCreated: 1563447093134},
    { RecordId: '187022', DateCreated: today's date}
]
```

I was trying to adjust the next code but no idea how to start....

```
let known = new Set(arrOld.map(res => res.RecordId));
let unknown = arrNew.filter(res => known.has(res.RecordId));
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `reduce()` to create an object from object array. Then loop through `arrNew` and change its props

```js
const arrNew =  [ { RecordId: '181049' },
             { RecordId: '187020'},
             { RecordId: '187022'} ]

const arrOld = [ { RecordId: '181049', DateCreated: 1563447093134 },
            { RecordId: '187020', DateCreated: 1563447093134 },
            { RecordId: '187021', DateCreated: 1563447093134 } ]
            
let obj = arrOld.reduce((ac, a) => (ac[a.RecordId] = a, ac), {});

arrNew.forEach(x => {
  if(obj[x.RecordId]){
    x.DateCreated = obj[x.RecordId].DateCreated;
  }
  else{
    x.DateCreated = (new Date()).getTime()
  }
})
console.log(arrNew)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a single map - there is no need for multiple loops. Just check if it exists, and if so, return the object with the DateCreated prop:

```js
const arrNew = [{
    RecordId: '181049'
  },
  {
    RecordId: '187020'
  },
  {
    RecordId: '187022'
  }
]

const arrOld = [{
    RecordId: '181049',
    DateCreated: 1563447093134
  },
  {
    RecordId: '187020',
    DateCreated: 1563447093134
  },
  {
    RecordId: '187021',
    DateCreated: 1563447093134
  }
]

const out = arrNew.map(o => {
  const f = arrOld.find(e => e.RecordId === o.RecordId)
  return f 
  ? {DateCreated: f.DateCreated, ...o} 
  : {DateCreated: new Date().getTime(), ...o}
})

console.log(out)
```

Comment: You are using multiple loops. It's just that they're implicit (`map` and `arrOld.find(...)`).

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to first create a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) of older registers from the `arrOld` array. Then, on a second step, you can use [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) on the `arrNew` array to map each register to the new objects having the `dateCreated` property.

```js
let arrNew =  [
  {RecordId: '181049'},
  {RecordId: '187020'},
  {RecordId: '187022'}
]

let arrOld = [
  {RecordId: '181049', DateCreated: 1563447093134},
  {RecordId: '187020', DateCreated: 1563447093134},
  {RecordId: '187021', DateCreated: 1563447093134}
]

let known = new Map(
    arrOld.map(({RecordId, DateCreated}) => [RecordId, DateCreated])
);

arrNew = arrNew.map(
    ({RecordId}) => ({RecordId, DateCreated: known.get(RecordId) || +new Date()})
);

console.log(arrNew);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```